# Is SOQL variable binding parameterization?

Tags: soql, soql-injection, bind-variable, parameterizedsearch

If you bind a variable in a SOQL query, is that equivalent to parameterization?

And is there a difference in behavior between static vs dynamic?

Comment: From the developer perspective, yes, these are equivalent. And yes, there is different behaviour between static and dynamic SOQL. This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you bind a variable in a SOQL query, is that equivalent to parameterization?

Yes, it is exactly parameterization under a different name. Binding is more of a programming term, compared to parameterization, where the query is typically stored, then executed at the database level with the parameters for the bindings provided.

> And is there a difference in behavior between static vs dynamic?

Static bindings are compiled to Apex, so can include method calls. Dynamic queries are not compiled or executed, and can therefore only be variables that are available in scope without calling any methods or evaluating any dot-notation relationships.